# Select element using jquery with lockerservice

Tags: lightning-aura-components, jquery, locker-service

I'm currently using the [fullcalendar lib](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/) to show some events on a basic calendar. Although working with lockerService activated, whenever I use the [Salesforce Lightning CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/cli_intro.htm) for code validation I get some errors.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
loadDataToCalendar :function(component, data){

  // get the div element
  var myDiv = component.find("calendar").getElement();

  // execute fullcalendar function
  $(myDiv).fullCalendar({ //some options and data });

  // call render function to update calendar
  $(myDiv).fullCalendar('render');
}
```

I get the following errors on the console using CLI:

> error  secure-window  Unexpected $
> Line: $(myDiv).fullCalendar({
>
> error  no-undef    '$' is not defined
> Line: $(myDiv).fullCalendar({
>
> error  secure-window  Unexpected $
> Line: $(myDiv).fullCalendar('render');
>
> error  no-undef    '$' is not defined
> Line: $(myDiv).fullCalendar('render');

How can I select a div element, with or without jquery,  and call the fullcalendar function while being compliant with the LockerService security architecture? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another case of the CLI tool reporting noise - and your code is fine To date we have not added any additional restrictions in LS from the first day of the pre release of Summer'16 - we have only opened up surface area. As for the CLI the issue is that it had to assume symbols like '$' it's not aware of are dangerous but with the latest version of the CLI you can use lint annotations to let the CLI know that $ is safe.

Answer (score 2):

To skip this kind of validations use the comment: /* globals $ */

For example in your js controller side:

```
({
    controllerFunction : function(component, event, helper){
        /* globals $ */

        ... rest of your code
    }
})
```

For more details go here: http://jshint.com/docs/